# Injecting IHttpClientFactory in structuremap

Tags: c#, httpclient, structuremap, structuremap3

We are using an older version of Structuremap (3.1.9.463). It's been a while since I used structuremap and HttpClients alongside and I wonter how to properly inject the IHttpClientFactory in structuremap.

Simply using `bootStrapper.For<IHttpClientFactory>().Use<HttpClient>();` won't work

A usage example is

```
public class DialogClient : IDialogClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public DialogClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Dialog:url"]);
    }
}
```

The project also use .NET Framework, not Core.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this in StructureMap with `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` package.

Having it installed, you can simply register `IHttpClientFactory` with following code:

```cs
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
configure.For<IHttpClientFactory>().Use(httpClientFactory);
```

Credit due to simillar issue for Simple Injector:
https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/843

Answer (score -1):

implement the interface

```
class MyHttpClientFactory: IHttpClientFactory
{
    public HttpClient CreateClient(string name)
    {
        // logic for creating client here
    }
}
```

and then register it

`For<IHttpClientFactory>().Singleton().Use<MyHttpClientFactory>();`